Finite field and splitting field


There are two graphs from GTM $167$,I am confused about the statement in the proof below Corollary $6.9$ that '$F(a)$ is a galois extension of $F$'. So why it is galois? I try but cannot find any connection between the statement and Theorem $6.5$.

Hi! Please typeset your mathematics (including the quoted text) using MathJax. Doing so will help prevent your question from being poorly received. Of course, MathJax has a learning curve, but if you make an honest initial attempt, users will generally be happy to help you improve and fix whatever errors you experience.

You can apply Theorem 6.5 in the following way: You know that $K/\mathbb{F}_p$ is a Galois extension by Theorem 6.5. The field $F(a)$ is between $K$ and $\mathbb{F}_p$, hence $K/F(a)$ is also a Galois extension.

@schiepy, but the statement is for $F(a)$/F.

You are absolutely right, I messed up the symbols. Note that $F(a)/\mathbb{F}_p$ is a Galois extension by Theorem 6.5 and therefore also $F(a)/F$, since $F$ is between these two.

@schiepy, I think this explanation is right.
